# Is there a better/another way to create list in react?

Tags: reactjs

In React, to render a list you generally `map` over and render elements like this:

```
list.map((itm, idx) => <li>{itm}</li>)
```

Can I refactor this to a component that is generic enough to handle different element types but still do the mapping for me? Aka,

```
<EasyList data={list} /> // tag would be "li" by default
<EasyList data={list} tag="p" /> // a customized tag name
```

What would be the best way to implement something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve exactly what you are describing in the way you are describing it. The implementation of `EasyList` could look something like this

```
const EasyList = ({data, tag: Elem = 'li'}) => {
  return data.map( (item, idx) => <Elem key={idx}>{item}</Elem>) 
}
```

and usage would look like

```
<EasyList data={list} /> // tag would be "li" by default
<EasyList data={list} tag="p" /> // a customized tag name
```

### [Demo to play with](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-fr2b8)

---

There are multiple ways you could implement this, so depending on needs you could go the route of a `render` prop, where you define the exact elements you need. Really it depends on what kind of control / granularity you want.

```
<EasyList data={seed} render={ (item, idx) => <li>{item}</li>} />
```

and the implementation with a render prop would look like

```
const EasyList = ({data, render}) => {
  return data.map(render) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer isn't much different than John Ruddell's, but I had already completed it before seeing his.

You can make this `EasyList` component as sophisticated as you need it to be. My example below shows that you can have it control the parent component (`ul` by default) and that the component types passed can be html element types (e.g. `ul`, `li`, `p`) or custom components such as `DivWithHeaderText` in my example.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const EasyList = ({ data, ListComponent = "ul", ItemComponent = "li" }) => {
  return (
    <ListComponent>
      {data.map(item => (
        <ItemComponent>{item}</ItemComponent>
      ))}
    </ListComponent>
  );
};
const myItems = ["Here", "are", "my", "list", "items"];
const DivWithHeaderText = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ border: "solid black 1px" }}>
      <div>Here is my header</div>
      <hr />
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <EasyList data={myItems} />
      <EasyList
        data={myItems}
        ListComponent={DivWithHeaderText}
        ItemComponent="p"
      />
    </>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit EasyList]

Comment: I think @John's answer is simpler, but thanks for your get involved :)